# iOS - CALayer setShadowColor not working

Tags: ios, layer, shadow

I need to set a bottom shadow to a button. I have the shadow but somehow I cannot change the shadow color. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
[self.buttonsBar.layer setShadowColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:227.0f/255 green:233.0f/255 blue:239.0f/255 alpha:1.0f].CGColor];
[self.buttonsBar.layer setShadowOpacity:1];
[self.buttonsBar.layer setShadowRadius:1];
[self.buttonsBar.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(0, 1)];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `self.buttonsBar.clipsToBounds = NO;`
also make sure your `self.buttonsBar.layer.masksToBounds = NO;`
first try large radius and offset to make sure you see them then reduce the numbers, sometimes it is not easy to see the shadow depending on the background colors ...